# IIS7 Url Rewrite module doesn't work

Tags: iis

I am tring set the rule as below:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="abcd.com/admin(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="xyz.com/admin{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

When I try to access to url:abcd.com/admin/login but action not work. Please help me about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The match url does not contain the domain, so you need to remove that:

```
 <match url="^admin(.*)" />
```

Comment: I have two domain access to folder source code.
Domain 1: abcd.com --> Deny access to backend
Domain 2: xyz.com  ---> can access to backend with path xyz.com/admin

If i use  <match url="^admin(.*)" /> ==> The iis block all domain access to backend :(

Thanks!